# jQuery: is() is not work for dynamic events?

Tags: jquery

I want to update **text** of anchor element dynamically based on its followed **div** element.First I've tried with `is()`its not worked for me as I expected, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcYpd/3/) for this.

```
$(document).on('click','a#toggle_info',function(){
   $("div#info").slideToggle('slow');

    if($("div#info").is(":visible"))
   {
      $(this).text('Hide');  
   }
   else
   {  
    $(this).text('Show');               
   }       
 });
```

Anyhow I found alternative to this as shown in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcYpd/2/).But I want to know the reason why my first approach is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using slideToggle so your dom need to wait for animation to finish.

what you can do is wrap code inside callback function.

```
$("div#info").slideToggle('slow',function(){
   if($("div#info").is(":visible"))
   {
      $('#toggle_info').text('Hide');  
   }
   else
   {  
    $('#toggle_info').text('Show');               
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [`:visible` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the animation.

Since the element is animated when you are making the check, it's always considered to be visible.  To fix this you have to make the check either *before* or *after* the animation.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `.slideToggle('slow')` is not finished and the code below is executed before.

and

```
if($("div#info").is(":visible")){
      $(this).text('Hide');  //$(this) here refers to div with id info not a tag
   }
```

This way your code will work

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dcYpd/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(document).on('click', 'a#toggle_info', function () {
        var that = $(this);
        if ($("div#info").is(":visible")) {
            that.text('Show');
        } else {
            that.text('Hide');
        }
        $("div#info").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show demo..?? because i have doubt on this code....because we are using toggle so in this case only either animation work

Comment: click multiple time in your example and in my example...you will see difference....show hide text are messed up...but yes we can use this too....but i think using callback is better....

Answer (score 0):

As you are using slideToggle() you have to wait to complete the animation or you change put the animation command as last one like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','a#toggle_info',function(){        
        if($("div#info").is(":visible"))
       {
          $(this).text('Hide');  
       }
       else
       {  
        $(this).text('Show');               
       } 
        $("div#info").slideToggle('slow');
     });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcYpd/8/)**</kbd>

or

You can use slideToggle callback function to change anchor text like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','a#toggle_info',function(){
        var anchorelm = $(this);
        $("div#info").slideToggle('slow', function(){
        if($("div#info").is(":visible"))
       {
          anchorelm.text('Hide');  
       }
       else
       {  
        anchorelm.text('Show');               
       } 
        });       
     });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcYpd/10/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','a#toggle_info',function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("div#info").slideToggle('fast',function () {
            var $that = $(this);
            $this.html(function (i, html) {
                return $that.is(":visible") ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
            });
        });      
     });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dcYpd/11/)

You can also use something like this,

```
$this.html(function (i, html) {
    return html === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
});
```